# What does Iterative Method Relaxation mean?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix. Consider the function $\phi(x)=\frac12 \langle Ax,x\rangle−\langle b,x\rangle$ and the iteration $x+\delta_iv_i\to x$ where $v_i$ is the $i$-th eigenvector of $A$ (normalized).

I don't understand what is the function $\phi(x)=\frac12\langle Ax,x\rangle−\langle b,x\rangle $? Does it refer to fixed point iteration such that $x+\delta_iv_i=\phi(x)=\frac12\langle Ax,x\rangle−\langle b,x\rangle $?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it just refers to the function $\phi$, which is a function that maps a vector $x$ to a scalar $\frac12\langle Ax,x\rangle-\langle b,x\rangle$. Are you unfamiliar with some of these symbols?

Comment: @Rahul no i do not understand phi equation here; what does this function mapping to a scalar do? do we need to find a step size to minimize this function, why? thanks